# Rewrite a complicated sentence with "it" I don't know what they refer to

Tags: sentence-meaning

"As I argue above, the United States was politically predisposed toward stimulating
consumption."
"But even as **it** delivered the necessary stimulus for the world to **emerge** from
the 2001 recession, **it** discovered, much as in the 1991 recovery, that jobs were not being
created."

Can you please rewrite the 2nd sentence? I've bolded the "it"s that I don't grasp what they refer to.
In addition, I know the meaning of "emerge" as to become known, however I don't how it combined in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe *it* refers to the United States. *Emerge* does have a meaning like the one you gave, but it also has at least one more

> [emerge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emerge)
>   to rise from an obscure or inferior position or condition

So, although the U.S. provided a stimulus that allowed the world to *rise out*/*get out* of the recession in 2001, the U.S. discovered that jobs were not being created, like in recovery that happened in 1991.